# Dynamic Auto Sorting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, sorting

I have a list that is dynamic and can change depending what the user selects. The Event types will never change but the Count will. The items in B1 and B2 are what the user can select that will change the items in The count column. The data needs to sort automatically from largest to smallest which I need help on however when I do a normal sort the data is not sorting correctly. (Yes, I know I need to highlight both columns and yes the data I am sorting by cannot be different types of data). The items in column A will not change, but the items in column b will. Attached is the formula that is in Column B for reference:

=IF($B$2=Sheet3!$B$2,COUNTIFS('Complaints Data'!H:H,Bar!A5,'Complaints Data'!N:N,Bar!$B$1),IF($B$2=Sheet3!$B$3,COUNTIFS(G!H:H,Bar!A5,G!N:N,Bar!$B$1),IF($B$2=Sheet3!$B$4,(COUNTIFS('Complaints Data'!H:H,Bar!A5,'Complaints Data'!N:N,Bar!$B$1)+COUNTIFS(G!H:H,Bar!A5,G!N:N,Bar!$B$1)),0)))

Can someone please help?

[image]

I do not mind doing VBA and tried it earlier today. But could not get it to work.

Can you explain how to use the code and the call button?

Comment: Sorts will not auto update.  Otherwise it might update while someone was entering data!  You can make a button that fires a short VBA script to resort your sheet.

Comment: You could create a cell_change event that triggers a sort function in VBA

Comment: [This stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621214/is-it-possible-to-sort-formula-results) should do what you need.  Then just make a button to call the function and put the button at the top of your sheet.

Comment: Can you explain the how the VBA code on that page works as well as how to make a call button. I am very new.

Answer (score 0):

Note, this is an outline, I have not recreated your data and attempted a trial.  If I have extra time or you need more help I will try to do so.

Here is that code with some comments: (all credit to [Luboš Suk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2717068/lubo%c5%a1-suk) from [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621214/is-it-possible-to-sort-formula-results))

```
Sub formulaSort()
    ' declare a variable as type worksheet:
    Dim testSheet As Worksheet
    ' assign that variable to "Sheet1", another option would be Activesheet
    Set testSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' declare a variable as type Range
    ' note that it looks like he does not use this variable.
    Dim rangeToSort As Range


    ' choose to use the variable testSheet with the following code
    With testSheet

        'dot assignment refers to "testSheet" every time the period is used without anything prior to it
        'change the 2, 2 and 18, 4 to 5, 1 and 47, 2 for your range
        'change the D2 to B5 for your sheet
        .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(18, 4)).Sort key1:=.Range("D2"), order1:=xlAscending


    End With

End Sub
```

To create a button, From the Developer ribbon, choose insert > form control > button (form control).
Draw a box with the cursor
for the name enter "forumlaSort"  (the name of your function in VBA, which should be listed in the box below)
Play around with size, font, color of button as needed.

Save your worksheet as an XLSM file. (Macro enabled.)

Comment: Thank you so much, but I am still having code issues. Here is the macro code and whenever I press the button I get an error that says "subscript out of range."                              Sub formulaSort()
    Dim testSheet As Worksheet
    Set testSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rangeToSort As Range
    With testSheet
        .Range(.Cells(1, 5), .Cells(2, 47)).Sort key1:=.Range("D2"), order1:=xlAscending


   End With
End Sub

Comment: @b.del Two Items:  Change "D2" to "B5", that is probably the out of range error.  Then it also looks like the cell reference is backwards.  It should be (Row, Column).  Thus your line should be ```.Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(47, 2)).Sort key1:=.Range("B5"), order1:=xlAscending```

Comment: It is still not working. I am still getting the same error:

Comment: @b.del It looks like the name of your sheet may be "Bar".  If so, you would need to change ```Set testSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")``` to ```Set testSheet = Sheets("Bar")```  Otherwise the sort seems to be working on my end.